# How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2, socks

How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2 to download a web page?

Comment: Related for Tor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096379/how-to-make-urllib2-requests-through-tor-in-python

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [SocksiPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/) module. Simply copy the file "socks.py" to your Python's lib/site-packages directory, and you're ready to go.

You must use **socks** before urllib2. (Try it `pip install PySocks` )

For example:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
```

You can also try pycurl lib and tsocks, for more detail, click on [here](http://panweizeng.com/archives/855).

Comment: One issue with that is: the DNS lookup by urllib doesn't seem to go through the proxy. (even with rdns option and SOCKS4 type)

Comment: Just want to note that sockipy on sourceforge has some nasty bugs. At minimum use the fork here: code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch
Since the project appears abandoned IMO someone should take that branch, change the name and write a blogpost so people don't continue to use this buggy (and imo not wonderfully written) lib.

Comment: I know this is old but what is wrong with the original sockipy? What bugs has it got?

Comment: Can't download socksipy anymore from your link.

Comment: @OJW there is another answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13214222/288875 which also makes the host name lookups go over the SOCKS proxy

Comment: Looks like the latest fork of SocksiPy is now here: https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

Answer (score 21):

Adding an alternative to pan's answer when you need to use many different proxies at the same time.

In that case you need to create an opener like you do with a http proxy. There is a code available in GitHub https://gist.github.com/869791

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, 'localhost', 9999))
print opener.open('http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp').read()
```

Comment: Hey, I was using the code from github. Unfortunately, the authentication doesn't work. I've passed in right username and password in the socksipyhandler.py, however, I get error (3, 'unknown username or invalid password'). 

I can confirm that my username password work, since my cURL command works with the same credentials.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out the issue, there was a typo in socks.py =), btw, great work. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

Since SOCKS is a socket level proxy, you have to replace the socket object used by `urllib2`. Please take a look a [this](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2006-04/msg01816.html) solution. If monkey patching is not good enough for you, then you can try to subclass or copy-modify the code from the `urllib2` standard library.