# Using urllib2 with SOCKS proxy

Tags: python, urllib2, socks

Is it possible to fetch pages with urllib2 through a SOCKS proxy on a one socks server per opener basic? I've seen the solution using setdefaultproxy method, but I need to have different socks in different openers.

So there is SocksiPy library, which works great, but it has to be used this way:

```
import socks
import socket
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "x.x.x.x", y)
```

That is, it sets the same proxy for ALL urllib2 requests. How can I have different proxies for different openers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/):

```
import pycurl
c1 = pycurl.Curl()
c1.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.google.com')
c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'localhost')
c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8080)
c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)

c2 = pycurl.Curl()
c2.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.yahoo.com')
c2.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'localhost')
c2.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8081)
c2.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)

c1.perform() 
c2.perform()
```

Comment: Wow, what's a nice pythonic API! :/

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can. I repeat my answer on [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100870/88231)
You need to create an opener for every proxy like you do with an http proxy. The code for adding this feature to SocksiPy is available in GitHub https://gist.github.com/869791 and is as simple as:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, 'localhost', 9999))
print opener.open('http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp').read()
```

For more information I've written an example running multiple Tor instances to behave like a rotating proxy: [Distributed Scraping With Multiple Tor Circuits](http://blog.databigbang.com/distributed-scraping-with-multiple-tor-circuits/)

Answer (score 0):

**== EDIT == (old HTTP-Proxy example was here..)**

My fault.. urllib2 has no builtin support for SOCKS proxying..

There are some '*hacks*' adding SOCKS to urllib2 (or the socket object in general) [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/478365-i-wanna-use-urllib2-get-page-socks-5-proxy-who-can-give-me-sample-code#post1848118).
But I hardly suspect that this will work with multiple proxies like you require it.

As long as you don't wan't to hook / subclass urllib2.ProxyHandler I would suggest to go with pycurl.

Comment: It ain't working. urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>. The proxy is working fine (so it's not its problem)

Comment: Strange, in my tests (I'm behind a http proxy) it works fine.
Did you try multiple simultanous connections?

Comment: No, just your snippet without authentication. Are you sure we both are talking about SOCKS proxies?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one socket for all openers and implementing socks is in socket level. So, you can't.
I suggest you to use pycurl library, it much more flexible.

Comment: is an easy way to use pycurl with 2.6 on windows?

Comment: nope, looks like project is dead (last update was 2 years ago)
and it doesn't compile on windows with new curl

Comment: *nope, (...) it doesn't compile on windows with new curl* How does compiling pycurl with newer versions of curl relate to using pycurl with newer versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use threading locks if there aren't too many connections being made at once, and you need to access from multiple threads:

```
import socks
import socket
import thread
lock = thread.allocate_lock()
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def GetConn():
    lock.acquire()
    import urllib2
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "x.x.x.x", y)
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(ARGUMENTS HERE)
    lock.release()
    return conn
```

You might also be able to use something like this every time you need to get a connection:

```
urllib2 = execfile('urllib2.py')
urllib2.socket = dummy_class() # dummy_class needs the socket module's methods
```

These are obviously not fantastic solutions, but I've put in my 2¢ anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

A cumbersome but working solution for using a SOCKS proxy is to set up provixy with proxy chaining and then set the HTTP_PROXY provided by privoxy via system variable or any other way.

Answer (score -3):

You could do you it by setting evironmental variable HTTP_PROXY in following format:

user:pass@proxy:port

or if you use bat/cmd, add before calling script:

set HTTP_PROXY=user:pass@proxy:port

I am using such cmd-file to make easy_install work under proxy.

Comment: This is for HTTP proxies, not SOCKS proxies.

Comment: And it doesn't solve the issue of a separate proxy per connection.