# What to do with “urlopen error” in python?

Tags: python

How do I rectify the error "urlopen error (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed" in python?
also i use a socks

Comment: You're going to have to provide *a lot* more context if you want to get some help...

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication?

Answer (score 0):

So `urlopen` cannot find the URL you desire.  What socks proxy are you using -- [socksipy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/), for example?  Maybe you haven't integrated it correctly in your use of (I imagine) `urllib2`.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537726/using-urllib2-with-socks-proxy) shows and points to some approaches for using a socks proxy with Python (`pycurl` is the way I'd choose to do it, if it was up to me).