# urllib2.proxyhandler in python 2.5

Tags: python, urllib2, httplib

In windows XP, python 2.5 and 2.6 I tested the following code:

```
import urllib2
proxy= urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8080'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
```

In the above code I get a BadStatusLine exception from line 349 of httplib.py.

I have a proxy running at 127.0.0.1:8080 which works (I can set a browser to use it with proxyswitchy, and when it's on I can get to sites which are blocked when it's off [in China]).

if I change it to a socks proxy,

```
proxy= urllib2.ProxyHandler({'socks': '127.0.0.1:8080'})
```

Then the proxy is not used at all.

I got the code from the question at [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2) and it's almost exactly the same - what could be going wrong?

Update: **urllib2 doesn't support socks proxies.**

Eventually got it working with curl:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()

#stupid GFW
if settings.CHINA:
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, '127.0.0.1')
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8087)
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urllib2 ProxyHandler is not designed to support the SOCKS protocol. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537726/using-urllib2-with-socks-proxy) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your local proxy is an HTTP proxy and not a socks proxy. Try this:

```
import urllib2
proxy= urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  I am located behind the great firewall of china.  This was compounding the problem.  The gfw was both breaking connections and doing DNS poisoning.

I have not managed to get any of the urllib2 solutions working.  But pycurl does seem to work and it gets around the "connection reset" problem.  fb/twitter were still blocked though.

Adding their IPS to my hosts file works - so for a larger scale solution, setting up a dns proxy is necessary.

Comment: To beat the GFW of CN, you need something more secure than SOCKS 5 proxies. Try SSH Tunnel.