# Tor with Pycurl usage?

Tags: python, pycurl, tor

Hi I want my crawler using Pycurl to use Tor. How can I do that? I know how to do that using httplib

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
print opener.open('http://www.google.com').read()
```

Please help.

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537726/using-urllib2-with-socks-proxy

Comment: Its not. This question is about pycurl implementation while that one is about httblin2 implementation. Anyways, thanx

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu I able to make **pycurl** works over **tor** using **socks5** proxy:

```py
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://whatismyipaddress.com/")
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, "127.0.0.1")
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 9050)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
c.perform()
```

Don't forget to install **tor**

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

To check that tor started you can run network monitoring command:

```
sudo netstat -lnptu
```

Which have something like this output. Please note that **tor** is on **127.0.0.1:9050** socket

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2701/skype      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1810/tor        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2187/dropbox
```