# Python equivalent of Ruby SOCKsify

Tags: python, ruby, proxy, socks

Ruby has this very nice gem that allows redirecting all network traffic trough a SOCKS proxy

```
require 'socksify'
TCPSocket::socks_server = "127.0.0.1"
TCPSocket::socks_port = 9050
rubyforge_www = TCPSocket.new("rubyforge.org", 80)
# => #<TCPSocket:0x...>
```

Is there any python equivalent?

Comment: my super googling skills gave me http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysocks/. There is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537726/using-urllib2-with-socks-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old question, but the more current solution would be to use https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks. This has a pip installable package (`pip install PySocks`) and can be used to monkey-patch socket as so:

```
import socket
import socks

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```