# Removing SOCKS 4/5 proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

This question is sort of the opposite of this:

[How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2)

Let's say I use a SOCKS 5 proxy using the method accepted in that question. How would I revert it back to no proxy in the **same** process?

i.e
start process
use proxy
..
remove proxy
...

Maybe there is a better way to use the proxy so that it's easier to remove it later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Abra kadabra

```
import socks,socket,urllib2
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
temp = socket.socket
socket.socket = socks.socksocket  
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read() // Proxy
socket.socket=temp
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read() // No proxy
```

Comment: Actually, you should restore socket.socket=temp in a "finally" clause.

Comment: @Robus how to restore socket.socket=temp in a "finally" clause?