# unable to access website with urllib and proxy

Tags: python, proxy, urllib, ssh-tunnel

I've opened a ssh tunnel with `ssh -D localhost:5678 me@server.com` and I want to use it in my python3 application.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.1
# -*- coding:Utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request

proxyhand = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"socks" : "http://localhost:5678"})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxyhand)
page = opener.open("http://www.mysite.com")
```

Where mysite.com can only be accessed from the network on server.com (that's why I use a ssh tunnel).

It works to access any other website with no limitations but for mysite.com I have a connection timed out error. The tunnel works as I can access mysite.com using firefox configured [as explained here](http://wiki.freaks-unidos.net/weblogs/azul/firefox-ssh-tunnel).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you be using `http` as the protocol, not `socks`? Thus:

```
proxyhand = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http" : "http://localhost:5678"})
```

Comment: With "http", I have a "BadStatusLine" exception for any website.

Comment: SOCKS is correct for the SSH redirect.  I think the problem is that `urllib` does not have SOCKS support.  You might have another hoop to jump through to get this working. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2