# Emulating SSH's SOCKS Proxy Tunnel in Python

Tags: python, encryption, socks, tunnel, emulation

I used to create a SOCKS connection between a windows client and linux server using SSH server and putty. However, the firewall between the client and server is now able to identify SSH packets and drop them.

I was wondering if I can emulate such behavior of SSH tunnels using python? Any recommendations on libraries or readings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, yes you can. Pick your poison.

- http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysocks/
- http://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/
- [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2)
- http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/httplib2.socks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) for your SSH. Here is a nice link [ssh-programming-with-paramiko](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/)

You can also try this [ssh module](http://zeth.net/post/332/) which uses paramiko.

Comment: The firewall between client and server is dropping SSH packets. If I use paramiko, I won't be able to establish the connection. Anyway, thank you for letting me know about this cool module. I will probably use it at some point in future.

Comment: Incorrect. Paramiko does not support SOCKS5 dynamic port forwarding, unfortunately.  If you need it, here is the ticket asking for support to be added: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/955