# How can I create a ssh tunnel using python like 'ssh -D'?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, tunnel

I have try to implement it using paramiko. But I find paramiko can only  launch a tunnel redirecting localhost:lport to remoteip:rport just like 'ssh -L'.

So I want to know how can I implement it using paramiko or use other library.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `-L` or `-R` options which forward specific ports, `ssh -D` establishes a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy for application-level port forwarding.

Assuming that's what you want, then according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997142/emulating-sshs-socks-proxy-tunnel-in-python/8998597#8998597), there are several Python modules which implements SOCKS clients/proxies, e.g. [PySocks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysocks/) and [SocksiPy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/). Unfortunately, I have never explored any of these options and cannot vouch for any of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am not good at English writing and what I want is to use python to launch a socks proxy just like 'ssh -D' does, and I can use the proxy for any program which needs transport from the port on my machine, for example web browser.