# How to make HTTP request through a (tor) socks proxy using python?

Tags: python, http, proxy, socks, tor

I'm trying to make a HTTP request using python. I tried changing my windows system proxy (using `inetcpl.cpl` )

```
url = 'http://www.whatismyip.com'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Cache-Control','max-age=0')
request.set_proxy('127.0.0.1:9050', 'socks')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response.read()
```

is giving me the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       response = urllib2.urlopen(request)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
>       return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 423, in _open
>       'unknown_open', req)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in unknown_open
>       raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) URLError:

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2/8100870#8100870

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm the OP. According to the answer given by Tisho, this worked for me:

```
import urllib, urllib2

##Download SocksiPy - A Python SOCKS client module. ( http://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/downloads/list )
##Simply copy the file "socks.py" to your Python's lib/site-packages directory, and initiate a socks socket like this.
## NOTE: you must use socks before urllib2.
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

url = 'http://ifconfig.me/ip'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Cache-Control','max-age=0')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response.read()
```

Comment: For me it only worked with port 9150. New update in Tor perhaps?

Comment: What's the benefit of 'Cache-Control', max-age=0? And neither 9050 nor 9150 works.

Answer (score 4):

It seems URLLIB2 doesn't support SOCKS as a proxy type(as explained here: [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2/8100870#8100870)). Look at http://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/ for an example of urllib+socks.