# Tunneling httplib Through a Proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, tunnel, httplib

I am trying to figure out how to send data to a server through a proxy. I was hoping this would be possible through tor but being as tor uses SOCKS it apparently isn't possible with httplib (correct me if I am wrong)

This is what I have right now

```
import httplib
con = httplib.HTTPConnection("google.com")
con.set_tunnel(proxy, port)
con.send("Sent Stuff")
```

The problem is, it seems to freeze when the tunnel is set. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the value of "proxy"? a name or IP address?

Comment: IP address. I am trying to use an http proxy in this example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use http proxy, it should be like this:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(proxyHost, proxyPort)
conn.request("POST", "http://www.google.com", params)
```

If you want to use SOCKS proxy, you can use SocksiPy as in this question: [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2)

Comment: Ahh I see, I had it slight off.

Comment: This behaviour easily brings python into the same league of vague or confusing language features as PHP... darn!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the correct answer is:

http://bugs.python.org/issue11448#msg130413

```
import httplib
con = httplib.HTTPConnection(proxyHost, proxyPort)
con.set_tunnel("www.google.com", 80)
con.send("Sent Stuff")
```

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-up to Khue Vu's answer, here's a complete example, the details of getting this working with a SOCKS proxy were more complex than expected.

First install PySocks with:

```
pip install PySocks
```

Then you need to manually set up your SOCKS proxy after instantiating your HTTPConnection and informing it that it's going to be using a proxy:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode

import socks

url = urlparse("http://final.destination.example.com:8888/")

conn = HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1', 9000) # use socks proxy address
conn.set_tunnel(url.netloc, url.port) # remote host and port that you actually want to talk to
conn.sock = socks.socksocket() # manually set socket
conn.sock.set_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9000) # use socks proxy address
conn.sock.connect((url.netloc, url.port)) # remote host and port that you actually want to talk to

request_path = "%s?%s" % (url.path, url.query)
conn.request("POST", request_path, post_data)
```

Note that the imports above are python3.x