# Fiddler is not able to capture the api calls and I'm using httplib2 library

Tags: python-3.x, fiddler, urllib, httplib2

But when I am using urllib, fiddler is able to capture all the calls.

When I am using **httplib2**,

```
import httplib2
import json

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
serviceurl = 'http://google.com'
response, content = h.request(serviceurl)
```

When I am using **urllib**,

```
import json
import urllib.request
import requests

url = 'http://google.com'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url,)
data=uh.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know urllib supports proxy servers, but httplib2 don't. So you need to modify your code. [Tunneling httplib Through a Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805773/tunneling-httplib-through-a-proxy)

Comment: As httplib2 doesn't support HTTPConnection, what should I do in that case.