# DNS over proxy?

Tags: python, dns, proxy

I've been pulling my hair out over the past few days looking around for a good solution to prevent DNS leaks over a socks4/5 proxy.

I've looked into the SocksiPy(-branch) module, and tried to wrap a number of things (urllib,urllib2,dnstools), but they all seem to still leak DNS requests. So does pyCurl.

I know that proxychains/proxyresolv can throw DNS requests over a socks4/5 proxy, and it does all it's magic with some LD_PRELOAD libraries to monkey-patch socket's functions, much like SocksiPy does, but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't send DNS over either a socks4 or socks5 proxy.

I suppose for linux I may be able to use CTypes with libproxychains.so to do my resolution, but I'm looking for something multi-platform, so I think monkey-patching the socket module is the way to go.

Has anyone figured out a good way to get around this? I want to do it all in-code for portability's sake, and I don't want to resort to running another proxy server!

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well I figured it out. You need to set your default proxy BEFORE you start using the socket (e.g. before you import anything that uses it.). You also need to monkeypatch the getaddrinfo part of socket, then everything works fine.

```
import socks
import socket

# Can be socks4/5
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4,'127.0.0.1', 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Magic!
def getaddrinfo(*args):
    return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]
socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

import urllib
```

This works and proxies all DNS requests through whatever module you import in lieu of urllib. Hope it helps someone out there!

EDIT: You can find updated code and stuff on my [blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20161011051014/http://fitblip.pub/2012/11/13/proxying-dns-with-python/)

Comment: Thanks for this code. It would be nice to explain the magical part that makes DNS work properly, since your blog is down.

Comment: Ah, good call! Sorry about that. It went ignored and you've inspired me to actually do something with my saturday night.

http://fitblip.pub/2012/11/13/proxying-dns-with-python/ 

(Please excuse any crazy CSS things that will be happening)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It does not work for me for some reason. Could you please check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517669/python-urllib2-with-tor-proxy-throws-http-error-403

Comment: @Alexandr: I've posted a possible solution on your question :)