# Python urllib2 with Tor proxy throws `HTTP Error 403`

Tags: python, urllib2, tor, socks

I am trying to parse a web page using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13214222/1329187) solution like the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import time
import random

----------------------
import socks
import socket

# Can be socks4/5
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,'127.0.0.1', 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Magic!
def getaddrinfo(*args):
    return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo
----------------------

import urllib2


# define urls
start_url = 'http://www.exmple.com'

# get web page
hdr = request_header()
req = urllib2.Request(start_url)
for key, value in hdr.items():
    req.add_header(key, value)

page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = bs(page.read(), 'lxml')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soupParse.py", line 159, in <module>
    all_r = main()
  File "soupParse.py", line 35, in main
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Here is the header function:

```
# create random request header
def request_header():
    # change default User-Agent of the request
    user_agent = ['Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20130401 Firefox/31.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/29.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD amd64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/28.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2226.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',]

    ua = random.choice(user_agent)
    hdr = {'User-Agent': ua,
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    return hdr
```

I am not very much familiar with this topic, so it is difficult for me to understand the problem. Please help. Thank you.

UPDATE

I was able to determine, that this error only occurs with `urllib2`. If I use `Requests` for example, there is no error. I did not put it as an answer, since I do not know why this problem exists. If somebody knows, I would be glad to hear it.

Good luck and happy scrapy!

Comment: Does the page need login?

Comment: @NunoAndré, No. It works fine without setting the socks piece.

Comment: It could be a problem with headers. Which headers are you sending?

Comment: @NunoAndré, See my edit. But it works with the same headers without socks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend firing up Wireshark and making sure that your requests are being proxied as you think they are.

BeautifulSoup may be the culprit here as it would logically be importing the socket module first, so try making your import the following:

```
import socks    # Import this first no matter what
import socket    
import re
import time
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

Comment: Thank you for returning to this question but your option does not work for me. I am getting the same error. Other propositions?

Comment: If you're getting a 403 forbidden, that means that either your proxy server is not authenticating you properly (or has auth and you aren't specifying anything), or something else is not happening that you're expecting. Your only course of action at this point is to get a packet capture of what your code is actually doing and figure out what's not happening as expected.

Comment: It does not give me the error if I use `Requests` instead of `urllib2`. How can I check if both, the http and the dns go over socks?

Comment: If `requests` works, but `urllib2` doesn't this is an error somewhere in your use of `urllib2`, since `requests` uses `urllib2` IIRC. Your only course of action really is to get a packet capture with wireshark and look at the actual request difference between `requests` and `urllib2`. Also why not just use `requests` if it works?

Comment: :) that is exactly what I am going to do. Thank you for help.