# Python socket implementation

Tags: python, sockets, namespaces, global-variables, monkeypatching

I am fairly new to python, I come from a strong C background however, and I was trying to figure out how this works: [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2)

The part I am having trouble understanding is that they overwrite `socket.socket` yet `socket.socket` is a 'type' as told by running `type(socket.socket)`. So I am confused about how you are capable of overwriting a type like that, or is `socket.socket` in this case actually a function they are redefining hence actually returning a different type? Normally if I run `type` on a function it returns that its a function or a method or whatever.

I guess what I am really trying to understand is what is happening under the covers?

Comment: you can also do stuff like `sys.stdout=my_log_file`

Comment: That makes sense to me because stdout is just a variable pointing to a file, but socket.socket is saying that its a type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess what I am really trying to understand is what is happening under the covers?

This is a great question.

Storing a variable in another namespace like this is called ["monkey patching"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

The code example isn't actually overwriting the *type*.  Instead, it updates the *socket* variable in the *socket* module namespace to point at a socks 4/5 class.   Then, when *urllib2* looks-up the *socket.socket* variable, it now uses the [*SocksiPy module*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/) instead of native sockets.

The import thing to know is that *socket.socket* is a variable that is initially set to point at the built-in socket type.  That variable can be updated to point at a new 4/5 socket type.  When *urllib2* looks up the variable, it uses the substitute instead of the original.

Conceptually, what is going on is roughly akin to this:

```
>>> socket = 'old_native_socket'
>>> def urllib2(url):
         return 'Looking up', url, 'using', socket

>>> socket = 'new_4_5_socket'
>>> urllib2('http://www.python.org')
Looking up http://www.python.org using new_4_5_socket
```

And here is a simple monkey patch example for the [*math*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html#module-math) module:

```
>>> import math
>>> def area(radius):
        return math.pi * radius ** 2.0

>>> math.pi = 3.1          # monkey patch
>>> area(10)
310.0
```

Comment: I don't understand how socket.socket is actually a variable though, cause then shouldn't it return back that it is a socket type instead of just type?

Comment: you are shadowing the class ... at the module level classes are just variables ...

Comment: Interesting ok. I am so used to C where once a type is set it is set in stone that this just broke all conventions for me. I didn't realize this was possible in python

Answer (score 1):

consider the following

```
class SomeClass:
     def __init__(self):
         print "I am some class!"

class SomeOtherClass:
     def __init__(self):
         print "I am some other class!!"

c1 = SomeClass()
c2 = SomeOtherClass()
SomeClass = SomeOtherClass #shadows the other class
c3 = SomeClass()
```

this is just hapening at the module level `socket`