# How to get python gspread to use a SOCKS proxy server for connections?

Tags: python, proxy, gspread

How could I get my script that's using [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to have the gspread connections to google's servers use a SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 0):

[SocksiPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/) should work for this, as per the SO question: [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2).

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

import gspread
# do whatever
```

If this is not the desired result, you may have to create a custom instance of the bundled [`HTTPSession` object](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/httpsession.py).