# Application using MQTT protocol from azure sdk, doesn´t work behind a corporative proxy

Tags: proxy, mqtt, raspbian-stretch

I´m newbie in this matter, and I don´t know why my application just work and runs in a open network, when is behind a proxy I have a return error.
I´m using a `raspberry zero`, with `raspbian Stretch`, using `azure-iot-sdk-python` and proxy `squid`

I already  try this things:

The proxy allow HTTPS connection, and it has all PORT are available and without any restriction and the address *****. azure-devices.net is put inside a whitelist in

```
$ nano / etc / squid / whitelist
```

Beyond that I set the proxy in the operate system, raspbian Stretch, in the

```
$ nano / etc / environment
```

the follow configurations:

export http_proxy = "http://192.168.2.254:3128/"

export https_proxy = "https://192.168.2.254:3128/"

export no_proxy = "localhost, 127.0.0.1"

And also in

```
$ nano ~ / .bashrc
```

export http_proxy = http: //192.168.2.254:3128

export https_proxy = https: //192.168.2.254:3128

export no_proxy = localhost, 127.0.0.1

And,

```
$ nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90proxy
```

Acquire :: http :: Proxy "http://192.168.2.254:3128/";

Acquire :: https :: Proxy "https://192.168.2.254:3128/";

```
from iothub_client import IoTHubClient, IoTHubTransportProvider, IoTHubMessage
import time

CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=******.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=***;SharedAccessKey=*********"
PROTOCOL = IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT


def send_confirmation_callback(message, result, user_context):
    print("Confirmation received for message with result = %s" % (result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = IoTHubClient(CONNECTION_STRING, PROTOCOL)
    message = IoTHubMessage("test message")
    client.send_event_async(message, send_confirmation_callback, None)
    print("Message transmitted to IoT Hub")

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

Error: File: /usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c Func: lookup_address_and_initiate_socket_connection Line: 282 Failure: getaddrinfo failure -3.
Error: File: /usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c Func: socketio_open Line: 765 lookup_address_and_connect_socket failed
Error: File: /usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c Func: on_underlying_io_open_complete Line: 760 Invalid tlsio_state. Expected state is TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_UNDERLYING_IO.
Error: File: /usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c Func: tlsio_openssl_open Line: 1258 Failed opening the underlying I / O.
Error: File: /usr/sdk/src/c/umqtt/src/mqtt_client.c Func: mqtt_client_connect Line: 1000 Error: io_open failed
Error: File: /usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func: SendMqttConnectMsg Line: 2122 failure connecting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use a HTTP proxy with (native) MQTT, they are 2 totally separate protocols.

If you can use MQTT over WebSockets then you should be able to use a HTTP proxy as WebSockets are initially established by upgrading a HTTP connection.

If you have a SOCKS proxy available on your network, then you may be able to use that with native MQTT. The following question has hints on how to use a SOCKS proxy with Python. [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2)