# how to access a website with python through tor, successfully? ports 8118 and 9050 don't work?

Tags: python, urllib2, tor

I'm trying to access a website with python through tor, but I'm having problems. I started my attempts with this thread and the one referenced in it: [How to make urllib2 requests through Tor in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096379/tor-with-python/2015649#2015649)

First I tried the original code snippet:

```
import urllib2
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"tcp":"http://127.0.0.1:9050"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

then I tried the modified code posted in one of the answers, which people said worked for them. Unfortunately, the code works in that it downloads the page, but it *doesn't* work because my IP address is still the same:

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
print opener.open('http://www.google.com').read()
```

I have TOR set up in the standard configuration, per the Ubuntu and TOR sites respective documentation, and nmap shows the TOR tcp proxy running on port 9050: `9050/tcp open  tor-socks` However, my IP address isn't changed when I run either of the above scripts. Is python not respecting the http environment variables, or is there a code problem that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TOR provides a SOCKS proxy. Since urllib2 can only handle HTTP proxies, you'll have to [use a SOCKS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2).

Comment: I thought that in the question I linked to, the user _was_ trying to send an HTTP request through TOR (since they were trying to crawl a page). The main answer suggested trying to connect through the actual TOR port (8118), but that didn't work for me, hence the new question.

Comment: @pythonscript Oops, you're totally right. Removed that part from the answer.