# Python fails Tor check using urllib2 to initiate requests

Tags: python, security, urllib2, tor

After reading through the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096379/tor-with-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711351/using-urllib-with-tor) on StackOverflow, I got a snippet of Python code that is able to make requests through a Tor proxy:

```
import urllib2
proxy  = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':'127.0.0.1:8118'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
print opener.open('https://check.torproject.org/').read()
```

Since Tor works fine in Firefox with TorButton, I expected it to work fine in Python. Unfortunately, included in the mess of HTML: `Sorry. You are not using Tor`. I am not sure why this is the case or how to get Tor working properly with `urllib2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've set up a proxy to your local Tor instance for the `http` protocol, but you're using `https` to talk to "check.torproject.org". Try:

```
print opener.open('http://check.torproject.org/').read()
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had not even considered this. Thank you very much.